# XSLT default template mode?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have several content type-specific XSLTs that until now have only been used independently of one another. I.e.: `content-type-A.xml` => `content-type-A.xslt`. However, a recent change requires them to be joined because new documents will contain aggregated content from multiple content types.

The main problem is that the content types share element and attribute names, so it's not possible to simply include the content type-specific XSLTs into a master aggregate XSLT. it seems like the most straightforward way to keep them separate is to apply a mode corresponding to the content type for each template in it's XSLT. This will require updating hundreds of templates as well as dependencies in other parts of the workflow that will need to be updated to use that initial mode when executing the XSLT.

Is there any way to declare a default mode for a template - or workaround to achieve the equivalent? Essentially, I want to declare once the mode for a template, and after that: all templates are in that mode unless specified, and all applied templates are to that mode unless specified.

Comment: You're right that the feature would be useful, and it has been added to XSLT 3.0. In 2.0, however, you could automate the process of adding a specific mode to every xsl:template and xsl:apply-templates element that current lacks one.

Comment: this is one of the nice things about XSLT being XML - you can write one stylesheet whose job is to modify another one.

Answer (score 2):

[XML Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) is the usual way to deal with the problems of recognition and collision that arise when disparate markup vocabularies have to be used in a single XML document.  Also, if you wish to maintain XSDs for the input "content type" documents separately, and if you also wish to have an XSD that governs the newly combined XML document, XML Namespaces will help bring sanity to both markup definition and transformation.

[XSLT modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes), combined with careful contextual adjustments to the match patterns, might help to isolate the effect of changes to the XSLT stages of your pipeline.  However, a careful architectural comparison of the effects of both approaches on long-term maintainability of the whole system would be prudent.

Comment: I considered that, but unfortunately in this case it would be far more disruptive because of the application built on the XML in question.

Comment: +1, I do agree namespaces would be ideal, but the content is defined in DTDs in another part of the workflow, over which I have less influence.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XSLT 3.0-compliant processor that supports `default-mode`:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#default-mode

Comment: I found this in the spec, and although XSLT 2.1 is not an option for my solution, I wanted to include it for completeness.

Comment: Note that XSLT 2.1 was renumbered XSLT 3.0, and the current draft is the one at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/

Answer (score 1):

Generate the XSLTs with modes added using XSLT (as suggested by Dr. Kay). This adds the mode passed in as a stylesheet variable as the default mode, while preserving existing modes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xso="dummy" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" xml:space="preserve" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" />
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="xso" result-prefix="xsl" />
   <xsl:param name="mode" required="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="xsl:template">
      <xso:template mode="{ (@mode, $mode)[1] }">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @mode|node()" />
      </xso:template>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="xsl:apply-templates">
      <xso:apply-templates mode="{ (@mode, '#current')[1] }">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @mode|node()" />
      </xso:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```